# Moving text up in a table

Tags: html, html-table, valign

I currently have a table that looks like this:
http://s8.postimg.org/gybzti0rn/Screen_Shot_2015_02_27_at_1_30_23_PM.png

I want to move the description of the boat up to the top of the image. I tried using valign="top", but this moved the description to the very top of the table, where the boat name is.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table border ="1">
<tr>
    <th> Boat Name </th>
  <th rowspan="2">Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="boatimage.png"></td>
  </tr>      
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make the question a bit clearer?

Maybe try CSS

```
<th style="display:block;position:relative;top:20px;" rowspan="2">
```

That will move it 20px from the top of it's cell

Comment: I would like to know how I can edit my code so that the description lines up with the top of the image

Comment: @Demi in that case see above - just change 20px to whatever suits

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a padding

```
<table border ="1">
<tr>
    <th> Boat Name </th>
  <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:top;padding-top:25px">Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://s.codeproject.com/App_Themes/CodeProject/Img/logo250x135.gif"></td>
  </tr>      
</table>
```

Because of the rowspan you added it will cover 2 row on that description `<th>` header and place text `description` accodingly in this case you have to manually adjust it by adding padding to align it to image `<td>` row border.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py14jc6c/)